# 400 Error Message when closing File Dialog box

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below code to get a file location. I'm using the file location of GetFile in a separate code that imports CSV data to one of my sheets.

The problem I'm running into is when the File Dialog Box opens up, if I don't select a file and click cancel I get a 400 error message. Can someone please let me know how to get rid of this error message?

```
Function GetFile() As String
Dim filename__path As Variant

filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Csv (*.CSV), *.CSV", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If filename__path = False Then Exit Function
GetFile = filename__path
End Function
```

As suggested in the comments below, the problem doesn't seem to lie in the function but in the macro calling on the function and receiving an error when it's false. The macro code is posted below; I've tried variations of GetFile = False to end the with statement but keep getting errors one way or the other.

```
Sub Import_log()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bus List Import").Activate

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=.Range( _
"$A$1"))
.Name = "logexportdata"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
.TextFilePlatform = 437
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Activate

End Sub
```

For now I'm using the code 'On Error GoTo MasterTab:' above with the MasterTab: label above the line to change the active sheet to the Master tab. I know this isn't best practice so I'd love if anyone had an answer :)
Here's full code below:

```
Sub Import_log()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bus List Import").Activate
On Error GoTo MasterTab:
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=Range( _
"$A$1"))
.Name = "logexportdata"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
.TextFilePlatform = 437
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
MasterTab:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you open the file dialog box? It should return a value on .show() indicating if a file is selected

Comment: I believe he problem is not in this code. For me it executes perfectly, no problems when I cancel the dialog. I think the problem is in that part where you try to get the data from your file. After no actual file is selected, the code still will try to open the file in `GetFile` location. In that case the location is `FALSE`, therefore the code fails. Debug your code to find out which line causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks ZygD, I believe your right, that makes a lot of sense. I'm troubleshooting that now

Comment: I posted the code above ZygD, I've tried variations of GetFile = False to end the with statement but continue to get errors. I'm geting to get it so If GetFile = False Then 'Master' Sheet is activated and sub ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if no file is selected you probably want to stop your macro. Then replace
    `If filename__path = False Then Exit Function`

with
   `If filename__path = False Then End`

exit function won't stop your macro and if you call GetFile from another function,  it will throw an error if you're trying to do something with GetFile = vbNullString or another unexpected value

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but this works great! Thanks for the answer and lesson scraaappy, I'm almost getting this whole VBA thing.. haha

Comment: @scraaappy Use of `End` will stop code execution abruptly.  Using `Exit Function` is the right way to terminate the execution of a function.  If your answer "solved" the OP's problem, then the real problem lies elsewhere in his code.  Using `End` like this is an ugly kludge that will only serve to hide other issues.

Comment: This did solve my problem, but I am running into other condition problems now elsewhere in my code which I believe have to do with the 'End'. Still troubleshooting so not sure, but I might need another answer to my original problem

Comment: @chris neilsen yes but that's exactly what we want. We want to avoid coming errors due to the user abort. So we abort the program and we want him to try again. What do you suggest as better practice?  
@user3026842 as @chris neilsen said, End will terminate abruptlty all execution. Since nothing more is running, you can't have any problem, right ? :)  
Now another error and you try to handle it. What I suggest you is to output the error description to know more about it : `debug.print "Error :" & Err.Number & " // " & Err.Description & " // " & Err.Source`  after label declaration `MasterTab:`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is

```
Sub Import_log()
    Dim filename__path As Variant

    '...

    filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Csv (*.CSV), *.CSV", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

    If Not filename__path = False then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
          "TEXT;" & filename__path, Destination:=Range( "$A$1"))
            '... Your code
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```